# How many different complex numbers $z$ satisfying equation $z^4 = 1$ are there?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm new to the complex numbers and i can't answer a simple question. Any help and explanation how to solve it?

Comment: do you mean $z^4 = -1$ ?

Comment: Take mod and set $z=x+iy $ see what you get.

Comment: @IntegrateThis No

Comment: How many roots does the polynomial $z^4 - 1$ have?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra says that it can have at most four different solutions (four solutions in total, but one or more of the roots might be a double root). To rule out double roots then use that such a root is also a root of $f'(z)$ so we must have $f(z) = f'(z) = 0$ in that case. This is not possible in this case so no double roots. This reasoning is not needed here as it's easy to solve the equation, but for more complicated equations it can be quite useful.

Comment: It is good practice to use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  Here the problem appears only in the title.  This might seem to "save time" or in some other way to be efficient, but in fact it leads to omission of your own thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Fundamental Theorem of Algebra:**
>
> An $n^{\text{th}}$ order polynomial has exactly $n$ solutions, taking into consideration the multiplicity of each distinct solution.

$$\begin{align}z^4&=1\\z^4&=e^{2i\pi k}\\z&=e^{\frac12i\pi k}\\&=\cos\left(\dfrac12\pi k\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac12\pi k\right)\end{align}$$

Putting $k=0,1,2,3...$
$$\begin{align}z&=\cos0+i\sin 0&=1\\z&=\cos\dfrac\pi2+i\sin\dfrac\pi2&=i\\z&=\cos\dfrac{3\pi}2+i\sin\dfrac{3\pi}2&=-i\\z&=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi&=-1\end{align}$$

Another method could be....
$$\begin{align}z^4&=1\\z^4-1&=0\\(z^2+1)(z^2-1)&=0\\z&=\pm i,\pm 1\end{align}$$

Comment: This sums up everything so well! Thank you.

Comment: Your quoting of the FTA is a red herring.  The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra asserts that every non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root.  It is not to difficult to show that if $a$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$ with $\deg(q) = \deg(p)-1$, from which it follows that an $n$-th degree polynomial has $n$ roots.  However, this says nothing about the roots being *distinct*.  Thus, in principle, $z^4-1$ could have a single root with multiplicity $4$.  The rest of your answer is fine.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, edited that part. Does it look any better?

Comment: @AwnonBhowmik Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

hint : $z^4-1=(z^2-1)(z^2+1)=(z-1)(z+1)(z+i)(z-i)$